# Error Transform Netsuite - Invoice a Credit Memo

Tags: javascript

Netsuite 2.0 -
En mi script de usuario en el before load estoy agregando un botón, adicional un script de cliente al formulario a través de las siguientes lineas:

```
var thisForm = scriptContext.form;
     thisForm.addButton({
     id : 'custpage_buttonvoidinv',
     label : 'Anular/Void',
     functionName: 'voidInvoice()'
});
thisForm.clientScriptModulePath = 'xxx';
```

Dicho botón contiene la lógica para realizar un transform de Invoice a Credit Memo, el problema es que al hacer el transform marca el error **"RCRD_DSNT_EXIST"**, he leído la documentación e indica que se debe a que la ruta del archivo no es correcta, pero es contradictorio porque de lado del cliente al dar click el botón si reconoce el evento y genera el objeto transform, incluso llega al before submit. Adicional he creado un transform en consola pero en versión 1.0 y si me funciona. Que podría estar fallando?

```
    var thisRecord = currentRecord.get(),
                    thisId = thisRecord.id;
                var tranDate = thisRecord.getValue('trandate'),//Validar con que fecha quedaran
                    tranId = thisRecord.getValue('tranid');

                var objRecord = record.transform({
                    fromType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                    fromId: thisId,
                    toType: record.Type.CREDIT_MEMO,
                    /*fromType: 'invoice',
                    toType: 'creditmemo',*/
                    isDynamic: true
                });

                objRecord.setValue('custbodyaplicar_a_factura',tranId);
                objRecord.setValue('trandate',tranDate);
                objRecord.setValue('memo','VOID');
var recordId = objRecord.save({
                //enableSourcing: true,
                ignoreMandatoryFields: true
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo que esta pregunta ya tiene un par de años, pero espero esto te sirva.

No mire en particular el código del Client Script que ejecuta el `record.transform` pero en el caso de estos scripts puedes usar la API 1.0 dentro de un ClientScript escrito en API 2.0 de la siguiente forma `window.nlapiTransformRecord`.

Espero te sirva, saludos!